# Symfony Single id is not allowed on composite primary key in entity

Tags: php, symfony-2, orm, doctrine-2, symfony3

Tenho uma view, onde mapeei 3 campos como chave primário e 2 desses campos são chaves estrangeiras

Conforme abaixo:

```
/**
     * @var NotaFiscal
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="NotaFiscal", inversedBy="itens")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="CODIGO", referencedColumnName="CODIGO")
     */
    private $notaFiscal;

    /**
     * @var Produto
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Produto")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="CD_PRODUTO", referencedColumnName="CD_PRODUTO")
     */
    private $produto;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="CD_LOTE")
     */
    private $lote;
```

Não consigo enxergar aonde está o erro... 
Single id is not allowed on composite primary key in entity

Answer (score 1):

Deixe `@ORM\Id` apenas na chave primária.

Para mais referência sobre mapeamento de campos e anotações do Doctrine, veja [Basic Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html)

Comment: Os 3 campos é uma chave composta.